# Stumped by relative imports

Tags: python

I don't know what's going on:

```
$ ls
__init__.py  main.py  module.py
$ cat main.py
from . import module
$ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import module
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#relative-imports-and-name):

> Relative imports use a module's `__name__` attribute to determine that module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to '`__main__`') then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file system.

Clarification: The `__name__` attribute will usually be the path a module has when it's being imported, e.g. in **foo/bar.py**, provided foo was the top-level package, `__name__` would be 'foo.bar'. In the special case of a .py file you're running directly, `__name__` evaluates to `'__main__'`, which means relative imports will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear: You cannot do relative imports in your main script. See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/ for details.

Comment: You mind explaining what the PEP says? I had a look and I'm still stumped.

Comment: @Tshepang: I had the same problem finding what I was supposed to see in the PEP. See my answer for the direct link to the explanation (excerpted in my answer).

Comment: `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` is not exactly clear. Are you sure you aren't taking your knowledge for granted?