# Python3: Attempted relative import in non-package

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I'm so sorry about this basic question, because it's similar to this:
[Stumped by relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923775/stumped-by-relative-imports)

But I'm trying to follow the PEP328
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision
and it doesn't work for me :(

These are my files:

```
dev@desktop:~/Desktop/test$ ls
controller.py  __init__.py  test.py
```

2to3 says all it's right:

```
dev@desktop:~/Desktop/test$ 2to3 .
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: No files need to be modified.
```

The content of the files:

```
dev@desktop:~/Desktop/test$ cat controller.py 
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

dev@desktop:~/Desktop/test$ cat __init__.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

dev@desktop:~/Desktop/test$ cat test.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
from .controller import Controller 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('running...')
```

But the import it's not working:

```
dev@desktop:~/Desktop/test$ python3 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .controller import Controller 
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
dev@desktop:~/Desktop/test$
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a script *within* a package; you are running `test`, *not* `test.test`. A top-level script can thus not use relative imports.

If you wanted to run a package as a script, you'd need to move `test/test.py` to `testpackage/__main__.py`, move one directory up in your shell to `~/Desktop` and tell python to run a package with `python -m testpackage`.

Demo:

```
$ ls testpackage/
__init__.py   __main__.py   __pycache__   controller.py
$ cat testpackage/controller.py 
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

$ cat testpackage/__init__.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

$ cat testpackage/__main__.py 
from .controller import Controller
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('running...')

$ python3.3 -m testpackage
running...
```

You cannot name the package `test`; Python already has such a package for the test suite and that'll be found before a package in the current working dir is found.

The alternative is to create a script *outside* of the package and import the package from the script.