# Why does my view function 404?

Tags: python, flask

Directory Structure:

[image]

`__init__`:

```
from flask import flask 

app = Flask(__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__'
    app.run()
```

Views:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

I hope someone can explain what I am doing wrong here -
I guess I'm not understanding how to properly import `app`. This results in a 404. However when views is moved back to `__init__` everything works properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitly import your `views` module in your `__init__`:

```
from flask import flask 

app = Flask(__name__)
from . import views
```

Without importing the module, the view registrations are never made.

Do keep the script portion outside of your package. Add a separate file in `Final_app` (so outside the `app` directory) that runs your development server; say `run.py`:

```
def main():
    from app import app
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__'
    main()
```

Comment: Is my directory structure correct or am i missing something else? Im unable to import views, No module named views

Comment: @Chris_S: your package setup is indeed convoluted as you put a script in the `__init__` file. How are you currently running the server, with `python app/__init__.py`?

Comment: Yes, should the contents of init be in their own file?

Comment: @Chris_S: See [Python3: Attempted relative import in non-package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20582335); you really should avoid putting scripts inside packages. Then use `from . import views` in `__init__`.

Comment: When I attempted `from . import views'  i was greeted with: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import'

When I moved everything from `__init__`  to its own file and tried `import views`  that resulted in `no module named views`

I think something else is going on here.

Comment: @Chris_S: when you use `__init__.py` as the script there is indeed no parent package, which is why I advocated creating a separate `run.py` script *outside* the `app` package.

Comment: Oh I missed the edited answer. Everything is working as it should now. Thank you for the help